# Calling a dialog activity to the map activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, customdialog

I'm working on a Campus Map App. The Map Activity is on the Main Activity, however, I have a different activity for the Custom Dialog.
I always get this custom dialog.

[image]

**When in fact I want it to appear like this.**

[image]

I have this code for this Activity

```
public class AdminActivity extends FragmentActivity{

  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AdminActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.layers)
           .setItems(R.array.layer_options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               // The 'which' argument contains the index position
               // of the selected item
           }
    });
    return builder.create();
  }

  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Dialog dialog=onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.show();
    }
}
```

And this code is a part from the main activity where I'm going to call the dialog..

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
AdminDialog adminDialog;
  switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.about:
        Intent aboutUs = new Intent("com.android.cmumap.ABOUT");
        startActivity(aboutUs);
        break;
    case R.id.search:

        break;
    case R.id.layers:
        adminDialog= new AdminDialog();
        adminDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "custom-tag-goes-here");
        break;
  }
  return false;
}
```

How do I achieve calling the map activity for my AdminActivity? Thank You.

Comment: are you getting any error when calling map activity for my AdminActivity?

Comment: my program stops as long as i tap the button that shows the dialog..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class should subclass `DialogFragment`, not `FragmentActivity`. Be sure to `@Override` the `onCreateDialog(...)` method. You can also get rid of your `onCreate(...)` method as that is not needed with a `DialogFragment`.

To display the `DialogFragment`, instead of using an `Intent` like you would for an `Activity`, do the following from your map activity. Note that I renamed your class because now it is not an `Activity` but rather a `Dialog`:

```
adminDialog= new AdminDialog();
adnimDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "custom-tag-goes-here");
```

Comment: No, that code should go in whatever activity you want to host this Dialog, which is probably the activity you use to display the map. Simply use that code when you want to display the dialog.

Comment: what do i put on custom-tag-goes-here?

Comment: I have an error here.. new AlertDialog.Builder(AdminActivity.this) it says it's undefined..

Comment: Whatever you want. Fragments can be created with a tag to make finding them later easier. If you don't plan on using the tag you can pass `null` instead.

Comment: Instead of using `AdminActivity.this` you should use `getActivity()`. That's how you get the Activity that is hosting the Fragment.

Comment: Did you rename your class to that? This is elementary stuff really.

Comment: The method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentManager, String)

Comment: Check what version of DialogFragment you're importing in the AdminDialog class. Is it `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment` or `android.app.DialogFragment`?

Comment: I had both.. Which one should I use?

Comment: You probably want to use `android.app.DialogFragment`. If you don't want to support Android before APIv11, it's safe to use the non-support library.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sir Nathan Walters

This is for the AdminDialog Activity for the Custom Dialog..

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AdminDialog extends DialogFragment{

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.layers)
           .setItems(R.array.layer_options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               // The 'which' argument contains the index position
               // of the selected item
           }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
}
```

And I have this for the main activity where the dialog is called..

```
AdminDialog adminDialog;

adminDialog= new AdminDialog();
adminDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "custom-tag-goes-here");
```